# lxml encoding changes while appending string to list

Tags: python, file, list, encoding, lxml

I'm using lxml and etree to parse an html-file. The code looks like this:

```
def get_all_languages():
    allLanguages = "http://wold.livingsources.org/vocabulary"
    f = urllib.urlopen(allLanguages).read()
    #inFile = "imLog.xml" 
    #html = f.read()
    #f.close()
    #encoding = chardet.detect(f)['encoding']
    #f.decode(encoding, 'replace').encode('utf-8')
    html = etree.HTML(f)
    #result = etree.tostring(html, pretty_print=True, method="html")
    #print result #is of type string
    #print type(result)
    return html
```

Than, I'm extracting some information from the webside and save it in an array.
While appending the string to an array, the encoding or format of the string changes. I think is some kind of unicode object or so??
So I thought it might not be challenging for me, because I remove it from the array and print it in an output file.

```
def print_file():
#outputfile
output = 'WOLDDictionaries.txt'
dataLanguage = get_data_all_languages()
dataDictionaries = get_site_single_lang()
outputFile = open(output, "w")
outputFile.flush()
for index, array in enumerate(dataLanguage):
    indexLang = index 
    for item in array:  
        string = item
        #indexLang = index
        outputFile.write(string + "\t")
    outputFile.write("\n")
    #outputFile.flush()
    for index, array in enumerate(dataDictionaries):
        #stringArray = str(array)
        indexDic = index
        #outputFile.write(index + stringArray + "\t")
        if(indexLang == indexDic):
            #outputFile.write(string + "\t")
            for data in array:
            #stringData = str(data)
            #outputFile.write(stringData + "\t")
                for word in data:
                    stringWord = word
                    outputFile.write(stringWord + "\t")
                outputFile.write("\n")

    #outputFile.flush()

outputFile.close()
```

Well this thougth was wrong. While printing it to a file, the encoding is still wrong.
What can I do to get the right characters?

Comment: Yes, `lxml` returns Unicode objects. Can you elaborate on what goes 'wrong' for you?

Comment: I'm extracting the strings from the html. The webpage includes several languages and is encoded in utf8. I'm appending the strings to an array.
In the last method, I extract the words from the array and write them in a textfile. I thought, that the characters would be ok after I extract them , but some characters are broken. E.g. : lËmÄn + ËÄlmyÄn instead of lˁmān + ˁālmyān (Arabic ).

So I'm looking for a method or a something to get the encoding right in the textfile.

Comment: I only have problems with special characters in some languages. Maybe that's the problem. All other unicode objects are extracted correctly.

Comment: How do you know the tool that is *reading* the text file is using the correct codec to decode the file data? What codec are you writing with?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. It was in the parser.
I changed the encoding in the parser and got the right encoding in the end.
The mothod now looks like this:

```
myparser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding = 'utf-8')
html = etree.HTML(f, parser=myparser)
#print etree.tostring(xml, pretty_print=True, method="xml")
#print type(xml)
return html
```